# Neo4j-Process to achieve Replication in Community Edition of Neo4j

Tags: java, neo4j

We are startups and working on Community Edition of Neo4j version 2.3.2 on windows for java based project by using the **neo4j-jdbc-2.3.2-jar-with-dependencies** .As we are newbie we are storing less information on Neo4j like saving less no of properties on the nodes, creating only important relation between nodes. We are also using couch-db to store our data.

Neo4j only have the important data.
Basicly, till now we were using the information store on Neo4j for our searching purpose only,  but now as slowly gradualy learning about Neo4j we want to use it for further purposes also.

**PROBLEM :-**
1: Like we want to increase the usage of Neo4j we want to know about the REPLICATION in Neo4j Community Edition to reduce the risk of loosing data.

Till what I have studied its only available in Enterprise solution. Is there any way to achieve it on Community Edition.

2: What is the actual use of default graph.db folder ?

Comment: Everything you're asking is documented on the Neo4j site, regarding features per edition (such as High Availability, which is essentially the replication feature). You'd need to come up with your own backup scheme for community edition - and how you do that is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

**Replication** means copying the data to another instance of Neo4j in order to provide a [high-availability cluster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-availability_cluster) and the ability to handle more simultaneous queries.

You've said that you want to "reduce the risk of loosing data" [sic], which means that you need **backup**, *not replication*.

Backup is available in Neo4j Community Edition. See [Chapter 5. Backup](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/backup/) in the [Neo4j Operations Manual](http://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/3.0/).

To answer your second question, the graph.db folder contains the backing files for the default database.